# concatenar ng models

Tags: angularjs, ionic

quiero concatenar todos los datos que ingreso cuando pido la direccion para enviarlos a un `ng-model` de la forma eje(carrera 20 # 19 107) este es mi formulario donde pido los datos en inputs por separados, la idea es enviarlos a un solo `ng-model`

```
<select style=" border:0px; background-color: white !important" ng-model="Direccion.Nomenclatura">
    <option ng-if="!direccion_nomenclatura">Seleccione</option>
    <option>Calle</option>
    <option selected>Carrera</option>
    <option>Transversal</option>
    <option>Diagonal</option>
    <option>Avenida</option>
    <option>Autopista</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="10" ng-model="Direccion.principal" name="principa" id="principa" class="imptsDir">
<p style="display: inline;">#</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="34" ng-model="Direccion.numero" name="numero" id="numero" class="imptsDir">
<p style="display: inline;">-</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="19" ng-model="Direccion.numero1" name="numero1" id="numero1" class="imptsDir">
<input type="text" placeholder="19" ng-model='Direccion.address' style="display: none !important;" name="address" id="address" class="imptsDir">
<label class="item item-input" style="    padding-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px;">
    <span class="input-label">Info Adicional</span>
    <input type="text" Placeholder="Apto, casa , bloque etc" ng-model="Direccion.aditional_info" name="info" id="info" style="border-bottom: solid 1px grey !important; margin-right: 30px; padding: 0px;">
</label>
```

todo quiero enviarlo al `ng-model='Direccion.address'`
esta es la parte del controlador donde la trato de asignar

```
$scope.Direccion = {}  
$scope.Direccion.city_id = ""  
$scope.Direccion.address = $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura +" "+ $scope.Direccion.numero +" #  "+ $scope.Direccion.numero1 +" - "+$scope.Direccion.aditional_info;  
$scope.Direccion.aditional_info = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error es que mantienes oculto siempre

```
<input type="text" placeholder="19" ng-model='Direccion.address' style="display: none !important;" name="address" id="address" class="imptsDir">
```

Debes eliminar el `style="display: none !important;"` y reemplazarlo por

```
ng-show="verAddress"
```

En tu controlador algo asi :

**FORMA 1**

```
 $scope.verAddress = false;
 $scope.enviar = function() {
     console.log($scope.Direccion);
     $scope.Direccion.address = $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura + " " + $scope.Direccion.numero + " #  " + $scope.Direccion.numero1 + " - " + $scope.Direccion.aditional_info;
     $scope.verAddress = true;
 }
```

Quedando tu formulario algo asi :

```
<select style=" border:0px; background-color: white !important" ng-model="Direccion.Nomenclatura">
    <option ng-if="!direccion_nomenclatura">Seleccione</option>
    <option>Calle</option>
    <option selected>Carrera</option>
    <option>Transversal</option>
    <option>Diagonal</option>
    <option>Avenida</option>
    <option>Autopista</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="10" ng-model="Direccion.principal" name="principa" id="principa" class="imptsDir">
<p style="display: inline;">#</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="34" ng-model="Direccion.numero" name="numero" id="numero" class="imptsDir">
<p style="display: inline;">-</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="19" ng-model="Direccion.numero1" name="numero1" id="numero1" class="imptsDir">
<input type="text" placeholder="19" ng-model='Direccion.address' ng-show="verAddress" name="address" id="address" class="imptsDir">
<label class="item item-input" style="    padding-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px;">
    <span class="input-label">Info Adicional</span>
    <input type="text" Placeholder="Apto, casa , bloque etc" ng-model="Direccion.aditional_info" name="info" id="info" style="border-bottom: solid 1px grey !important; margin-right: 30px; padding: 0px;">
</label>
<input button ng-click="enviar()" value="Enviar"></input>
```

Esta es una opcion, si es que tienes un boton que haga una accion y quieras ver el cambio, SI QUIERES ver el cambio de inmediato una vez que esten todos los campos completados, basta con utilizar el tag `ng-change="updateAddress()"`

**FORMA 2**

```
<select style=" border:0px; background-color: white !important" ng-change="updateAddress()" ng-model="Direccion.Nomenclatura">
    <option ng-if="!direccion_nomenclatura">Seleccione</option>
    <option>Calle</option>
    <option selected>Carrera</option>
    <option>Transversal</option>
    <option>Diagonal</option>
    <option>Avenida</option>
    <option>Autopista</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="10" ng-model="Direccion.principal" name="principa" id="principa" class="imptsDir">
<p style="display: inline;">#</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="34" ng-change="updateAddress()" ng-model="Direccion.numero" name="numero" id="numero" class="imptsDir">
<p style="display: inline;">-</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="19" ng-change="updateAddress()" ng-model="Direccion.numero1" name="numero1" id="numero1" class="imptsDir">
<input type="text" placeholder="19" ng-model='Direccion.address' ng-show="verAddress" name="address" id="address" class="imptsDir">
<label class="item item-input" style="    padding-left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px;">
    <span class="input-label">Info Adicional</span>
    <input type="text" ng-change="updateAddress()" Placeholder="Apto, casa , bloque etc" ng-model="Direccion.aditional_info" name="info" id="info" style="border-bottom: solid 1px grey !important; margin-right: 30px; padding: 0px;">
</label>
```

Y en tu controlador

```
$scope.verAddress = false;
$scope.Direccion = {};
$scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura = "";
$scope.Direccion.numero = "";
$scope.Direccion.numero1 = "";
$scope.Direccion.aditional_info = "";
$scope.updateAddress= function() {
if ($scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura != "" && $scope.Direccion.numero != "" && $scope.Direccion.numero1 != "" && $scope.Direccion.aditional_info != "") {
    $scope.Direccion.address = $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura + " " + $scope.Direccion.numero + " #  " + $scope.Direccion.numero1 + " - " + $scope.Direccion.aditional_info;
    $scope.verAddress = true;
}
```

**EDIT**

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/zKXNJE)

**EDIT 2**

```
.controller('registrarDireccionCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, Users, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, ionicToast, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS) {

  $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
  $scope.Direccion = {};
  $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura = "";
  $scope.Direccion.numero = "";
  $scope.Direccion.numero1 = "";
  $scope.Direccion.aditional_info = "";
  $scope.Direccion.token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  $scope.updateAddress= function() {
      if ($scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura != "" && $scope.Direccion.numero != "" && $scope.Direccion.numero1 != "" && $scope.Direccion.aditional_info != "") {
      $scope.Direccion.address = $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura + " " + $scope.Direccion.numero + " #  " + $scope.Direccion.numero1 + " - " + $scope.Direccion.aditional_info;
      }
  }

  var id = localStorage.getItem('user_id')
  var urlr = "http://abbie-core.herokuapp.com/api/users/" + id + "/addresses/new"

  $scope.registrarDireccion = function() {
      $scope.showLoadingProperTimes = function() {
          $ionicLoading.show({
              templateUrl: "templates/registro.html"
          });
      };
      $scope.showLoadingProperTimes();
      Users.registrarDireccion($scope.Direccion, urlr).then(function(argument) {

          console.log(argument)
          $ionicLoading.hide({});
          $scope.showToastRegDir();

      })
  };
  $scope.showToastRegDir = function() {
      ionicToast.show('Registro exitoso', 'bottom', false, 3000);
  };
 })
```

Comment: me sigue mandando undefined undefined #  undefined - undefined @sioesi

Comment: Hice un codepen y funciona todo bien. Puedes dejar el codigo de tu controlador para ver que esta fallando, te dejare el link del codepen.

Comment: @ingFR ya edite mi respuesta, te deje codepen

Comment: @ingFR Debes concatenar los valores DENTRO de una funcion, ya que tu declaras esos valores siempre vacios por lo tanto siempre tu concatenación sera vacia, tu controlador deberia estar asi : Edito

Comment: la sigue mandando null @sioesi

Comment: @ingFR viste el Codepen? Viste que funcionaba el codigo? Yo creo que realmente estas implementando mal las respuestas que aqui te dejamos!

Comment: @ingFR Y la verdad es imposible poder ayudarte si no completas tu codigo en tu pregunta y no como respuesta!, vamos a ver si podemos seguir ayudandote! puedes dejar que mas haz intentado hacer

Comment: @ingFR puedes actualizar tu codigo HTML? para ver quien llama a la funcion `registrarDireccion()`

Comment: @ingFR mira http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/zKXNJE comente tu codigo que no puedo acceder y sigue funcionando....

Comment: ya lo hice amigos era q tenia pproblemas con el select que aqui en ionic no se despliega y lo mandaba vacio @sioesi

Comment: Bueno!, me alegro que te haya funcionado!, @ingFR de todas maneras el codigo que proporcionaste no es el mismo que ocupas, debes hacer una pregunta menos amplia y mas especifica, con todos los datos necesarios para que en el foro podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que en tu `controller` accedas al `ng-model` mediante el `$scope.Direccion`, simplemente concatena los datos cuando los proceses allí de la siguiente forma:

```
$scope.Direccion.address = $scope.Direccion.address + $scope.Direccion.numero + $scope.Direccion.numero1 + $scope.Direccion.aditional_info;
```

Comment: ya lo intente y los manda "undefined undefined #  undefined - undefined" @joriusR

Comment: Agrega el código de tu `controller` y como lo procesas para ver un poco más y poder ayudarte

Comment: La idea era que editaras tu respuesta añadiendo dicho código...

Answer (score 0):

este es mi controlador @sioesi

```
    .controller('registrarDireccionCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q, Users, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, ionicToast, $rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS) {

    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $scope.Direccion = {}
    $scope.Direccion.city_id = ""
    $scope.Direccion.principal = "";
    $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura = "";
    $scope.Direccion.numero = "";
    $scope.Direccion.numero1 = "";
    $scope.Direccion.aditional_info = "";
    $scope.Direccion.address="";
    $scope.Direccion.token = localStorage.getItem("token");

    var id = localStorage.getItem('user_id')
    var urlr = "http://abbie-core.herokuapp.com/api/users/" + id + "/addresses/new"

    $scope.registrarDireccion = function() {
         if ($scope.Direccion.principal != "" && $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura != "" && $scope.Direccion.numero != "" && $scope.Direccion.numero1 != "" ) {
      $scope.Direccion.address = $scope.Direccion.Nomenclatura + " " + $scope.Direccion.principal + " # " + $scope.Direccion.numero + " - " + $scope.Direccion.numero1;
      }
        $scope.showLoadingProperTimes = function() {
            $ionicLoading.show({
                templateUrl: "templates/registro.html"
            });
        };
        $scope.showLoadingProperTimes();
        Users.registrarDireccion($scope.Direccion, urlr).then(function(argument) {

            console.log(argument)
            $ionicLoading.hide({});
            $scope.showToastRegDir();

        })
    };
    $scope.showToastRegDir = function() {
        ionicToast.show('Registro exitoso', 'bottom', false, 3000);
    };
})
```